# Does componentWillRecieveProps is always called before render or is it other way around

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I am trying to dispatch an action from componentWillRecieveProps and then the reducer is called. Reducers data is used in the component. 
I am getting error of variable being undefined.
I think render is loaded before execution of componentWillRecieveProps.

So i want to ask if render is loaded first or componentWillRecieveProps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will componentWillRecieveProps run every time props are received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36011875/will-componentwillrecieveprops-run-every-time-props-are-received)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`componentWillReceiveProps` is called before `render`.

Here's a diagram of which lifecycles are called when (up to React 16.3):

[image: Legacy React lifecycle diagram]
* *Where 'initialization / setup props and state' is the* `constructor`.

..

**New lifecycles**:

It's worth noticing that `componentWillReceiveProps` is [considered legacy and should be avoided in 'new' code](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/2000/1*sn-ftowp0_VVRbeUAFECMA.png) since React `16.3`. The legacy lifecycles will be removed as of React 17.

Here's a dynamic diagram of which lifecycles are used at what moment per React version: http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/

You can read more about component lifecycles [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **Yes**,

**Note:** **componentWillReceiveProps** with **getDerivedStateFromProps** in **React 16.3**

Please check: [Replacing ‘componentWillReceiveProps’ with ‘getDerivedStateFromProps’](https://hackernoon.com/replacing-componentwillreceiveprops-with-getderivedstatefromprops-c3956f7ce607)

Also, please have a look at **Component Creation LifeCycle** and **Component Update Life Cycle**
and also **DO's** and **Dont's** which is **super important!**

**Creational Life Cycle hooks:**

[image]

**Update Life Cycle hooks:**

[image]